# Moving python to anothe drive in windows10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10

I installed python 3.9.1 in my windows10 to following path:

```
'C:\\Users\\RD\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39'
```

Now my C drive doesn't have space and I want to move python with all installed packages into D drive. what should I try for this?

Comment: Probably easier to uninstall first and reinstall to another driver selecting during installation

Comment: @piertoni but I will loss my all installed packages. I don't want to loss that. Can you have any other solution?

Comment: You can move the python folder, than you have to adjust the python path (Control Panel => System => Change Settings => Advanced => Environment Variables). This can work depending on which other packages you have installed.
Also pip freeze can help:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/